# C# - code to order by a property using the property name as a string

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

What's the simplest way to code against a property in C# when I have the property name as a string?  For example, I want to allow the user to order some search results by a property of their choice (using LINQ).  They will choose the "order by" property in the UI - as a string value of course.  Is there a way to use that string directly as a property of the linq query, without having to use conditional logic (if/else, switch) to map the strings to properties.  Reflection?

Logically, this is what I'd like to do:

```
query = query.OrderBy(x => x."ProductId");
```

**Update:**
I did not originally specify that I'm using `Linq to Entities` - it appears that reflection (at least the GetProperty, GetValue approach) does not translate to L2E.

Comment: I think you'd have to use reflection, and I'm not sure you can use reflection in a lambda expression... well, almost certainly not in Linq to SQL but maybe when using Linq against a list or something.

Comment: @Telos: There's no reason that you can't use reflection (or any other API) in a lambda. Whether or not it will work if the code gets evaluated as an expression and translated into something else (like LINQ-to-SQL, as you suggest) is another question entirely.

Comment: This is why I posted a comment instead of an answer. ;)  Mostly used to Linq2SQL...

Comment: You can use dynamic Linq - check out [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) blog. Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby) StackOverFlow post...

Comment: Just had to overcome the same problem.. see my answer below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21936366/775114

Answer (score 149, accepted):

I would offer this alternative to what everyone else has posted.

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop = typeof(YourType).GetProperty("PropertyName");

query = query.OrderBy(x => prop.GetValue(x, null));
```

This avoids repeated calls to the reflection API for obtaining the property. Now the only repeated call is obtaining the value.

**However**

I would advocate using a `PropertyDescriptor` instead, as this will allow for custom `TypeDescriptor`s to be assigned to your type, making it possible to have lightweight operations for retrieving properties and values. In the absence of a custom descriptor it will fall back to reflection anyhow.

```
PropertyDescriptor prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(YourType)).Find("PropertyName");

query = query.OrderBy(x => prop.GetValue(x));
```

As for speeding it up, check out Marc Gravel's [`HyperDescriptor`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HyperPropertyDescriptor.aspx) project on CodeProject. I've used this with great success; it's a life saver for high-performance data binding and dynamic property operations on business objects.

Comment: Note that reflected invocation (i.e. GetValue) is the most costly part of reflection. Metadata retrieval (i.e. GetProperty) is actually less costly (by an order of magnitude), so by caching that part, you are not really saving yourself that much. This is going to cost pretty much the same either way, and that cost is going to be heavy. Just something to note.

Comment: @jrista: invocation is the most costly, to be certain. However, "less costly" does not mean "free", or even close to it. Metadata retrieval takes a non-trivial amount of time, so there is an advantage to caching it and no *disadvantage* (unless I'm missing something here).

In truth this should really be using a `PropertyDescriptor` anyway (to account for custom type descriptors, which *could* make value retrieval a lightweight operation).

Comment: Searched for hours for something like this to handle sorting a ASP.NET GridView programmatically:

PropertyDescriptor prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(ScholarshipRequest)).Find(e.SortExpression, true);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61635636/efcore-3-1-3-throwing-execption-for-orderby?noredirect=1#comment109026507_61635636

Had a problem with reflection it didn't work out in EfCore 3.1.3. It seems to throw error in EfCore 2 which needs to be activated for the warnings.

Use the answer of @Mark below

Comment: I receive the following:
InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<MyObject>
.Where(t => t.IsMasterData)
.OrderBy(t => t.GetType().GetProperty("Address").GetValue(
obj: t,
index: null).GetType())' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

Comment: @AdamRobinson In both cases, i receive the error `"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."` Any thoughts or advices, please?

Answer (score 103):

I'm a little late to the party, however, I hope this can be of some help.

The problem with using reflection is that the resulting Expression Tree will almost certainly not be supported by any Linq providers other than the internal .Net provider.   This is fine for internal collections, however this will not work where the sorting is to be done at source (be that SQL, MongoDb, etc.) prior to pagination.

The code sample below provides IQueryable extention methods for OrderBy and OrderByDescending, and can be used like so:

```
query = query.OrderBy("ProductId");
```

Extension Method:

```
public static class IQueryableExtensions 
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName)
    {
        return source.OrderBy(ToLambda<T>(propertyName));
    }

    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderByDescending<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName)
    {
        return source.OrderByDescending(ToLambda<T>(propertyName));
    }

    private static Expression<Func<T, object>> ToLambda<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
        var propAsObject = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(propAsObject, parameter);            
    }
}
```

Regards, Mark.

Comment: Excellent solution - I was looking for exactly that. I really need to dig into the Expression trees. Still very rookie at that. @Mark, any solution to do nested expressions?
Say I have a type T with a property "Sub" of type TSub that itself has a property "Value". Now I'd like to get the expression Expression<Func<T, object>> for the string "Sub.Value".

Comment: Why do we need the `Expression.Convert` to convert `property` to `object`? I'm getting a `Unable to cast the type 'System.String' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.` error, and removing it seems to work.

Comment: @Demodave if i remember correctly. `var propAsObject = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));` and just use `property` in place of `propAsObject`

Comment: Gold. Adapted for a .Net Core 2.0.5.

Comment: Got error `LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types`

Comment: This solution is great because, if you want to order objects in a LINQ to objects query, just call one of the `OrderBy` methods, compile it, store the resulting delegate in a variable, and use it in your LINQ query.

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution! Thank you!

Comment: @SimonScheurer did you ever find an answer to your case?

Answer (score 62):

I liked the answer from [@Mark Powell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689199/c-sharp-code-against-a-property-using-the-property-name-as-a-string/#answer-21936366), but as [@ShuberFu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689199/c-sharp-code-against-a-property-using-the-property-name-as-a-string/#answer-21936366) said, it gives the error `LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types`.

Removing `var propAsObject = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));` didn't work with properties that were value types, such as integer, as it wouldn't implicitly box the int to object.

Using Ideas from [Kristofer Andersson](https://forums.asp.net/t/1580414.aspx?LINQ%20to%20SQL%20Generic%20OrderBy/#3983399) and [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208214/construct-lambdaexpression-for-nested-property-from-string/#answer-16208620) I found a way to construct the Queryable function using the property name and have it still work with Entity Framework. I also included an optional IComparer parameter. *Caution:* The IComparer parameter does not work with Entity Framework and should be left out if using Linq to Sql.

The following works with Entity Framework and Linq to Sql:

```
query = query.OrderBy("ProductId");
```

And [@Simon Scheurer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689199/c-sharp-code-against-a-property-using-the-property-name-as-a-string/#answer-21936366) this also works:

```
query = query.OrderBy("ProductCategory.CategoryId");
```

And if you are not using Entity Framework or Linq to Sql, this works:

```
query = query.OrderBy("ProductCategory", comparer);
```

Here is the code:

```
public static class IQueryableExtensions 
{    
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string propertyName, IComparer<object> comparer = null)
{
    return CallOrderedQueryable(query, "OrderBy", propertyName, comparer);
}

public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderByDescending<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string propertyName, IComparer<object> comparer = null)
{
    return CallOrderedQueryable(query, "OrderByDescending", propertyName, comparer);
}

public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ThenBy<T>(this IOrderedQueryable<T> query, string propertyName, IComparer<object> comparer = null)
{
    return CallOrderedQueryable(query, "ThenBy", propertyName, comparer);
}

public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ThenByDescending<T>(this IOrderedQueryable<T> query, string propertyName, IComparer<object> comparer = null)
{
    return CallOrderedQueryable(query, "ThenByDescending", propertyName, comparer);
}

/// <summary>
/// Builds the Queryable functions using a TSource property name.
/// </summary>
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> CallOrderedQueryable<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string methodName, string propertyName,
        IComparer<object> comparer = null)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");

    var body = propertyName.Split('.').Aggregate<string, Expression>(param, Expression.PropertyOrField);

    return comparer != null
        ? (IOrderedQueryable<T>)query.Provider.CreateQuery(
            Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable),
                methodName,
                new[] { typeof(T), body.Type },
                query.Expression,
                Expression.Lambda(body, param),
                Expression.Constant(comparer)
            )
        )
        : (IOrderedQueryable<T>)query.Provider.CreateQuery(
            Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable),
                methodName,
                new[] { typeof(T), body.Type },
                query.Expression,
                Expression.Lambda(body, param)
            )
        );
}
}
```

Comment: Geez, man, are you Microsoft? :) That `Aggregate` fragment is awesome! It takes care of virtual views created from EF Core model with `Join`, since I use properties like "T.Property". Otherwise ordering after `Join` would be impossible producing either `InvalidOperationException` or `NullReferenceException`. And I do need to order AFTER `Join`, because most queries are constant, the orders in views are not.

Comment: @DavidSpecht I'm just learning Expression Trees, so everything about them is now black magic to me yet. But I learn quickly, C# interactive window in VS helps a lot.

Comment: how to use this?

Comment: @Dat Nguyen Instead of `products.OrderBy(x => x.ProductId)`, you could use `products.OrderBy("ProductId")`

Answer (score 13):

Yes, I don't think there's another way than Reflection.

Example:

```
query = query.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty("ProductId").GetValue(x, null));
```

Comment: I receive the error `"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."` Any thoughts or advices, please?

Comment: You can check my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67630860/9071943) to know the reason why @FlorinVîrdol

Answer (score 7):

**Warning ⚠️**

You just can use `Reflection` in case that data is in-memory. Otherwise, you will see some error like below when you work with `Linq-2-EF, Linq-2-SQL, etc.`

[@Florin Vîrdol's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689199/c-sharp-code-to-order-by-a-property-using-the-property-name-as-a-string#comment114417240_1689212)

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object
> GetValue(System.Object)' method and this method cannot be translated
> into a store expression.

**Why**

Because when you write code to provide a query to `Linq query provider`. It is first translated into an *SQL statement* and then executed on the *database server*.

(See image below, from https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-expression)

[image]

**Solution ✅**

By using [Expression tree](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/expression-tree), you can write a generic method like this

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderDynamic<T>(IEnumerable<T> Data, string propToOrder)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var memberAccess = Expression.Property(param, propToOrder);        
    var convertedMemberAccess = Expression.Convert(memberAccess, typeof(object));
    var orderPredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(convertedMemberAccess, param);

    return Data.AsQueryable().OrderBy(orderPredicate).ToArray();
}
```

And use it like this

```
var result = OrderDynamic<Student>(yourQuery, "StudentName"); // string property
```

or

```
var result = OrderDynamic<Student>(yourQuery, "Age");  // int property
```

And it's also working with in-memory by converting your data into `IQueryable<TElement>` in your generic method return statement like this

```
return Data.AsQueryable().OrderBy(orderPredicate).ToArray();
```

See the image below to know more in-depth.

[image]

[**Demo on dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0qP0Wf)

Answer (score 5):

```
query = query.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty("ProductId").GetValue(x, null));
```

Trying to recall exact syntax off the top of my head but I think that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

More productive than reflection extension to dynamic order items:

```
public static class DynamicExtentions
{
    public static object GetPropertyDynamic<Tobj>(this Tobj self, string propertyName) where Tobj : class
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Tobj), "value");
        var getter = Expression.Property(param, propertyName);
        var boxer = Expression.TypeAs(getter, typeof(object));
        var getPropValue = Expression.Lambda<Func<Tobj, object>>(boxer, param).Compile();            
        return getPropValue(self);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var ordered = items.OrderBy(x => x.GetPropertyDynamic("ProductId"));
```

Also you may need to cache complied lambas(e.g. in Dictionary<>)

Answer (score 2):

Reflection is the answer!

```
typeof(YourType).GetProperty("ProductId").GetValue(theInstance);
```

There's lots of things you can do to cache the reflected PropertyInfo, check for bad strings, write your query comparison function, etc., but at its heart, this is what you do.

Answer (score 1):

Also [Dynamic Expressions](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions) can solve this problem.
You can use string-based queries through LINQ expressions that could have been dynamically constructed at run-time.

```
var query = query
          .Where("Category.CategoryName == @0 and Orders.Count >= @1", "Book", 10)
          .OrderBy("ProductId")
          .Select("new(ProductName as Name, Price)");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use a powerful tool name Expression an in this case use it as an extension method as follows:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string ordering, bool descending)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var property = type.GetProperty(ordering);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
    MethodCallExpression resultExp = 
        Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), (descending ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy"), 
            new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType }, source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));
    return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
}
```