# Avoid switch case -linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby)

```
  switch (sort) {
                case "Title":
                    queryResults = queryResults.OrderBy(r => r.Title);
                    break;
                default:
                    queryResults = queryResults.OrderBy(r => r.LastName);
                    break;
```

Is there any way I can get rid of the switch block above?

Can I do some thing like:

```
queryResults = queryResults.OrderBy(r => r."sort");
or
queryResults = queryResults.OrderBy(r => r.sort);
```

Comment: You'll find your answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby

Comment: The solutions provided won't work for most linq providers, please see my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21936366/775114

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you wanted to do this completely dynamic, you could use some reflection (simple example):

```
string prop = "Title";
var q = queryResults.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(prop).GetValue(x, null));
```

I wouldn't consider this the nicest solution in any case though. Whether this really makes sense for you depends on where you get the property name from (if you get it from reflection, too, or not) and how many properties there are.

Answer (score 5):

This should do it

```
queryResults = queryResults.OrderBy(r => sort == "Title" ? r.Title : r.LastName)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [DynamcLinq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). I haven't touched it in over a year, but I had the expected results.  Your code would change to:

`queryResults = queryResults.OrderBy(sort);`

Oh cool, it's also a [NuGet package too](https://nuget.org/packages/DynamicLINQ)