# Sorting using property name as string

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I would like my Web API to be able to sort its output by a string parameter such as this one:

`http://myapi.com/api/people?skip=0&take=50&orderBy=lastName&descending=true`.

Because I also have pagination support (with `skip`and `take`) in my API, I would like the `orderBy` and `descending` parameter to be applied to the SQL query directly, so that the correct result comes from the database.

When doing this however, the code can become very hard to manage when trying to match the parameters for `orderBy` with the actual properties of the classes I wish to sort by just using string comparisons.

I have found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689199/c-sharp-code-against-a-property-using-the-property-name-as-a-string/21936366#21936366) which is supposed to work with LINQ to Entities and thus also with the new EF7, however when I try to compile this code using the new Core CLR, I get the following message:

> Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>' to 'string'

The code from the solution that fails is the `OrderBy<T>`method:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName)
{
    return source.OrderBy(ToLambda<T>(propertyName));
}
```

It seems like the new Core CLR does not support this attempt. Is there another way to get the solution to work with the new CLR? If no, what other alternatives do I have to enable sorting using EF7 without resulting in countless `if` or `switch` statements to compare the input strings to the property names?

Comment: Why don't you use OData on your Web API? http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Which line of code gives you this error? Include the snippet that's failing here.

Comment: I've looked at OData before. Does it work correctly with the new ASP.NET 5 and EF7? Does it map the sorting parameters to the SQL query correctly?

Comment: @ChrisF the error is in the `OrderBy<T>`method at `return source.OrderBy(ToLambda<T>(propertyName));`

Comment: oData works correctly with asp.net 5 and EF7.

Comment: Can you include `ToLambda<T>(propertyName)` method?

Comment: I guess that you try to call .OrderBy(ToLambda<T>(propertyName)) instead of .OrderBy(propertyName) and then since you are using overloads things all get messed up. on your actual list try to do myList.OrderBy(propertyName); it might give a compiler error which would mean that your list is not typeof(IQueryable<T>) then you know you have to do myList.AsQueryable().OrderBy(propertyName); it has nothing to do with the CLR just you mixing up the overloads you took from that other post.

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira I'm intrigued by OData and spent the last couple of hours researching it. However I cannot find a library that supports the latest build of ASP.NET 5. The latest [github](https://github.com/OData/WebApi) build is 8 months old and seems very much dead.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET 5 in production already? It still is Release Candidate

Comment: No, but I'm working on a project that will incorporate the new ASP.NET 5 framework. Still ways to go before production.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution from your link uses an "Expression.Convert" which most of the time doesn't work with LINQ to Entities.

Here is a working extension method:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string propertyName)
{
    // LAMBDA: x => x.[PropertyName]
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x");
    Expression property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(property, parameter);

    // REFLECTION: source.OrderBy(x => x.Property)
    var orderByMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "OrderBy" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2);
    var orderByGeneric = orderByMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSource), property.Type);
    var result = orderByGeneric.Invoke(null, new object[] { source, lambda });

    return (IOrderedQueryable<TSource>)result;
}
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [EF+](http://entityframework-plus.net/) on GitHub.

You can find other methods to order by property name in my repository: [GitHub](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus)

- OrderByDescending
- ThenBy
- ThenByDescending
- AddOrAppendOrderBy
- AddOrAppendOrderByDescending

---

**EDIT**: Answer sub-question

> Is it possibly to sort by navigation properties using something like
>   this, e.g. a property name "NavigationProperty.PropertyName"

Yes, you can either split the string and loop to create the expression with the property path or use a real expression evaluator.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Eval-Expressions.NET](http://eval-expression.net/)

This library allows you to execute all LINQ method dynamically.

See: [LINQ Dynamic](http://eval-expression.net/linq-dynamic-example)

```
var result = list.OrderByDynamic(x => "NavigationProperty.PropertyName");
```

Comment: Is it possibly to sort by navigation properties using something like this, e.g. a property name "NavigationProperty.PropertyName"