# Iterate through property and creating an Expression<Func<>> with the result

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, expression

Im not used to working with expression funcs, but my problem is:
I get the name of a property as a string, i then need to convert this to the appropriate expression.

Currently im doing something like this:

```
if (string.Equals(propertyString, "customerNo", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    return _repo.DoSomething(x=>x.CustomerNo);
}
if (string.Equals(propertyString, "customerName", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    return _repo.DoSomething(x => x.CustomerName);
}
```

With the repo function something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ICustomer> DoSomething(Expression<Func<IObjectWithProperties, object>> express)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

What i would like to do, is use reflection like this:

```
var type = typeof(IObjectWithProperties);
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    if(string.Equals(property.Name,propertyString,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        return _repo.DoSomething(x => x.PROPERTY);
}
```

But I can't figure out a way to generate the expression func from the propertyinfo

EDIT: Mong Zhu's answer, i am able to create an expression using the property.

The reason i need this expression, is that im trying to dynamically set the orderby in an iqueryable.

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> List(Expression<Func<IObjectWithProperties, object>> sortColumn)
{
    using (var context = _contextFactory.CreateReadOnly())
    {
        return context.Customers.OrderBy(sortColumn).ToList();
    }
}
```

Using the answer like this:

```
public Customer Test(string sortColumn){

        var type = typeof(IObjectWithProperties);
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            if (string.Equals(property.Name, sortColumn, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                Expression<Func<IObjectWithProperties, object>> exp = u =>
                (
                    u.GetType().InvokeMember(property.Name, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, u, null)
                );

                return _customerRepository.List(exp);
            }
        }
}
```

I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : variable 'u' of type 'IObjectWithProperties' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

EDIT:

The Customer return type inherits the IObjectWithProperties:

```
public class Customer: IObjectWithProperties
{
     //properties
}
```

Comment: "I get the name of a property as a string" where do you get it from? user input? can you influence the source ?

Comment: from a controller, sadly i have no control over this

Comment: might it be that Customer is a `partial class` which serves as an extension for an existing database model?

Comment: that is correct yes

Comment: ok I learned a lot about Expression trees. From the point of applicability and especially readabilty I would advise you to stay with the if/else approach. I guess it can be solved but the effort is high and I guess the readability will suffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after digging around I found a working solution for EF in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21936366/5174469).

It has to be slightly modified

```
private static Expression<Func<T, object>> ToLambda<T>(string propertyName)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(property, parameter);
}
```

The call would look like this:

```
var type = typeof(IObjectWithProperties);
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    if (string.Equals(property.Name, propertyString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        var result = DoSomething(ToLambda<IObjectWithProperties>(property.Name));
    }
}
```

I will assume that `Customer` is an partial class which implements the interface `IObjectWithProperties` and an extension to a existing database table. So your orderby method should look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> DoSomething(Expression<Func<IObjectWithProperties, object>> sortColumn)
{
    using (var context = _contextFactory.CreateReadOnly())
    {
        return context.Customers.OrderBy(sortColumn).Cast<Customer>().ToList(); 
    }          
}
```

The important thing that you need to do here is to call `Compile()` which will allow to be translated into an sql statement and send to the server for querying.
Since you are using an Interface as input parameter for the `Func` the compiler
seems not be able to deduce that you partial class implements this interface.
So a further explicit `Cast<Customer>()` call is necessary to establish the correct return type.

I hope this is understandable and helps you to solve also the second problem

This solution translates also the `OrderBy` clause to SQL.

Disclaimer:

Unfortunately it works with `string` properties, but up to now NOT with `Int32`.
I am still trying to figure out why.

EDIT:

Meanwhile I found another solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44071949/5174469) by [David Specht](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2355006/david-specht)

This extension class can really be used as copy paste and it works on either type. Here is the important code that you need:

```
public static class IQueryableExtensions
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string propertyName, IComparer<object> comparer = null)
    {
        return CallOrderedQueryable(query, "OrderBy", propertyName, comparer);
    }

    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderByDescending<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string propertyName, IComparer<object> comparer = null)
    {
        return CallOrderedQueryable(query, "OrderByDescending", propertyName, comparer);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Builds the Queryable functions using a TSource property name.
    /// </summary>
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> CallOrderedQueryable<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string methodName, string propertyName,
            IComparer<object> comparer = null)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");

        var body = propertyName.Split('.').Aggregate<string, Expression>(param, Expression.PropertyOrField);

        return comparer != null
            ? (IOrderedQueryable<T>)query.Provider.CreateQuery(
                Expression.Call(
                    typeof(Queryable),
                    methodName,
                    new[] { typeof(T), body.Type },
                    query.Expression,
                    Expression.Lambda(body, param),
                    Expression.Constant(comparer)
                )
            )
            : (IOrderedQueryable<T>)query.Provider.CreateQuery(
                Expression.Call(
                    typeof(Queryable),
                    methodName,
                    new[] { typeof(T), body.Type },
                    query.Expression,
                    Expression.Lambda(body, param)
                )
            );
    }
}
```

And your order method would look simply like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> DoSomething(string propertyName)
{
    using (var context = _contextFactory.CreateReadOnly())
    {                
        return context.Customers.OrderBy(propertyName).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to work if im using a class, but my IObjectWithProperties is an interface

Comment: Ignore my comment, the error is elsewhere in the code

Comment: Let me extend my question a bit, since this now results in a problem where i use the expression

Comment: No problem, i really appreciate any help you can offer

Comment: @JonasOlesen basically you need to do something like `.OrderBy(x => express.Compile().Invoke...` but I don't get which role the `IObjectWithProperties` plays in selecting a sorting column. does Customer implement `IObjectWithProperties` ? otherwise I cannot make sense of it

Comment: Yes it does, my bad, missed that when i cleaned up the example for SO

Comment: @JonasOlesen. ok then I got your answer, give me a minute to reedit my post. Can you please update your question with this necessary information. so we make it coherent

Comment: @JonasOlesen ok I made an edit, using your newest information. Especially related to the interface. Have a look

Comment: This only works if i call .ToList() beforehand, meaning i load all the data into memory beforehand, if i try to do it before .ToList() i get the error: 
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object Invoke(Customer)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @JonasOlesen ok I tested it on a database table with an extended class. This solution works at my machine. Have a look.

Comment: This method still transforms it into an ienumrable, if you look at the sql generated by your suggestion vs if i just do .OrderBy(x=>x.customerNo), i can see that your suggestion omits the ORDER BY from the sql, and performs the ordering in memory instead

Comment: @JonasOlesen crap. It always feels like *almost there* but it ain't :D that's a tough nut

Comment: Ye :p at this point im tempted to just stick to the if statement hell

Comment: @JonasOlesen ok, I found one solution. It translates the orderby into sql. But `int32` cannot be used apparently. Haven't figured out why yet

Comment: @JonasOlesen found a better solution. It works on either type. Learned a lot though. If it helped you you might mark it as accepted ;) cheers mate

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ill give this a try and if it doesnt work, ill stick to if / else :)

Comment: @JonasOlesen you are welcome, thanx for the opportunity to dig again in expression trees ;)